Do i need atomic or mutex protection for sequential access in different threads in C++?
I have a vairable x.
Thread 1 read & write x.
Then thread 2 read & write x, this is guaranteed to happen after thread 1's modification.
int x;

void task(){
    ++x;
}

// 1. thread 1 runs task()
// 2. after 1 finished, thread 2 runs task()
// 3. goto 1 or 2

In this case, threads are sure not to access x simultaneously, do i need to use atomic or mutex to make sure thread 1's modification is visible to thread 2?
I guess this is undefined behavior by the C++ standard?
But can it work correctly in practice?
I got the question while reading a boost asio example.
There the async receive operations are always sequential on the time line, but can be performed by different threads(though the example only use one worker thread). I wonder if a normal(no atomic or mutex) member vairable modification in the receive handler would work correctly.

While you most likely don't need synchronization primitives (atomic, mutex, semaphore, etc) you could probably make use of marking x volatile. This would guarantee that reads and writes to x stay in order with other visible side-effects, although that would require another side-effect that enforces the order (that I assume you have already).
See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

The question is - if not using a mutex or acquire/release atomic, how do you know the access is sequential?  You're using informal terms like thread 2 runs "after" thread 1, but what enforces that?  If it's a mechanism that ensures a happens-before ordering in the sense defined by the C++ memory model, then all is well; if not then behavior is undefined.  You really don't want to get into questions about "does it work in practice"; it's hard to get any certainty even if you know a lot about the compilers being used, and impossible if you want your code to be portable or future-proof.

Either way, we can't judge whether the happens-before ordering is correctly enforced, without seeing the actual code that achieves this.

Yes. You need because there is only you can guarantee that your own resource is safe form access by multithread.

Normally this is made legal by whatever runs your thread. For example, std::thread:
std::thread::thread(func) constructor:

The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f on the new thread of execution.

(bold mine)
std::thread::join():

The completion of the thread identified by *this synchronizes with the corresponding successful return from join().

(bold mine)
See this for my attempt to explain what "synchronizes with" is.

Presumably ASIO provides the same guarantees.

I doubt ASIO does that. It rather uses a thread pool.

@3CxEZiVlQ By "the same" I mean provides the same synchronization guarantees.
